# Yii 1 particular field sorting issue

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

I need sorting in admin panel or admin page by particular field in `ASC` and `DESC` order.

`SORT_ORDER` field are sort. I try to `actionindex()` in sorting but not working and also call `actionadmin()` not working but call to `actionadmin()`

`http://localhost/mate/admin/admin/index.php?r=sdmattsFurniture/admin`

Above is my url.

CONTROLLER:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('SdmattsFurniture');
    $this->render('index',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}

public function actionAdmin()
{
    $model=new SdmattsFurniture('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['SdmattsFurniture']))
        $model->attributes=$_GET['SdmattsFurniture'];

    $this->render('admin',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

GRIDVIEW:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'sdmatts-furniture-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    /*'filter'=>$model,*/
    'columns'=>array(
        'furniture_id',
        'furniture_name',
        'furniture_code',
        'furniture_dimension',
        'sort_order',
        array(
              'name'=>'furniture_cost',
              'value' => function($data) {
                return round($data->furniture_cost, 0, 100);
            },

           ),

        array(
              'name'=>'furniture_image',
              'type' => 'raw',
              'value' =>'CHtml::image(Yii::app()->baseUrl."../../uploads/".$data->furniture_image,"",array("width"=>120,"height"=>120))',

           ),



        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
));
```

Comment: Please share your code from SdmattsFurniture model, especially search() method

Answer (score 0):

your question is not that clear , maybe below code what you need :)

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('SdmattsFurniture');        
    $dataProvider->criteria->order  = 'sort_order asc';
    $this->render('index',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}

public function actionAdmin()
{
    $model=new SdmattsFurniture('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['SdmattsFurniture']))
        $model->attributes=$_GET['SdmattsFurniture'];
    $model->dbCriteria->order = 'sort_order asc';
    $this->render('admin',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```